# JQuery Dropdown Link/Take off link?

Tags: jquery, html

I've got a dilemma with a dropdown I'm working on. It has to be a clickable menu and not on hover.

The problem is my menu contains links all the way through, so the sub menu has a link but that also has a dropdown inside it which is hidden.

The issue is if I take the link off the sub menu then the user can't get to that page, but if I leave it on then I can't show the dropdown inside it because it will link to the sub menu page.

What's the best way to resolve this issue/common way of building this dropdown?

Thanks

HTML

```
<!-- Dropdown -->
        <ul>
            <!-- Menu Item -->
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.menulink.com">Menu 1</a>
                <!-- Sub menu -->
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <!-- When clicked show sub menu or link to page? -->
                        <a href="http://www.menusublink.com">Sub Menu 1</a>
                        <!-- Sub Sub Menu hidden -->
                        <ul style="display: none;">
                            <li><a href="http://www.menusubsublink.com">Sub Sub Menu 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.menusubsublink.com">Sub Sub Menu 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.menusubsublink.com">Sub Sub Menu 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <!-- Menu Item -->
            <li><a href="http://www.menu1link.com">Menu 2</a></li>
            <!-- Menu Item -->
            <li><a href="http://www.menu1link.com">Menu 3</a></li>
            <!-- Menu Item -->
            <li><a href="http://www.menu1link.com">Menu 4</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Why does your Sub Menu 1 element also need a link? Is this necessary?

Comment: It's just the way the site I'm working on works, because some categories may not have that subsub dropdown so I guess you'd need to keep that link there incase the category didn't have them.

Comment: where is your jQuery code ?

Comment: If you could post some of your jQuery code or if you could insert jsfiddle link here then it would be really easy to picture and solve the problem.